# Get order(descending) wise records from dynamodb using golang

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I'm integrating dynamodb with my application. I want to perform basic operation with dynamodb. The code that I'm showing is to fetch 10 latest records means(first 10 records in descending order). But it will showing me some error of given below:-

Code:-

```
 params := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
    TableName: aws.String(tableName),
    KeyConditions: map[string]*dynamodb.Condition{
        "Type": {
            ComparisonOperator: aws.String("NULL"),
            AttributeValueList: []*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                {
                    S: aws.String("updated_time"),
                },
            },
        },
    },
    ScanIndexForward: aws.Bool(false),
    Limit:            aws.Int64(10),
}
// params.Limit = aws.Int64(10)
result, err := dbSvc.Query(params)
fmt.Println("result.Items:- ", result.Items)
fmt.Println("err:- ", err)
```

I want to fetch the records in descending order of `updated_time` I'm also passing the limit 10 in the params but it is showing the `error` is

Table data

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "updated_time": {
                "N": "1623145913"
            },
            "added_time": {
                "N": "1623145913"
            },
            "bid_amount": {
                "N": "100"
            },
            "user_id": {
                "S": "1"
            },
            "bid_currency": {
                "S": "INR"
            },
            "uuid": {
                "S": "c2a0df1b-253d-49cc-a0c4-2bc30425e1b9"
            },
            "card_id": {
                "S": "9s8x7gf98asd79gfa"
            }
        },
        {
            "updated_time": {
                "N": "1623145912"
            },
            "added_time": {
                "N": "1623145912"
            },
            "bid_amount": {
                "N": "100"
            },
            "user_id": {
                "S": "1"
            },
            "bid_currency": {
                "S": "INR"
            },
            "uuid": {
                "S": "f962d2b9-50e8-4bbc-89bd-086bd0a83b31"
            },
            "card_id": {
                "S": "9s8x7gf98asd79gfa"
            }
        },
        {
            "updated_time": {
                "N": "1623146186"
            },
            "added_time": {
                "N": "1623146186"
            },
            "bid_amount": {
                "N": "100.6"
            },
            "user_id": {
                "S": "1"
            },
            "bid_currency": {
                "S": "INR"
            },
            "uuid": {
                "S": "4c1c5998-5d9a-434a-aa41-baa09c95095e"
            },
            "card_id": {
                "S": "9s8x7gf98asd79gfa"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Count": 3,
    "ScannedCount": 3,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

> ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element
> status code: 400, request id: 37acb1eb-83dc-491b-b649-c39705c0c08f

Comment: The Query operation works within an item collection, i.e. items that share the same partition key. I don't see the partition key mentioned here, what does your Table look like?

Comment: @Maurice see the update

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what your PK looks like but I guess `updated_time` is possibly the sort key (since you're trying to sort on it). If so, you cannot query an index/PK on the sort key only, you must use the partition key as well. So, assuming `uuid` is the partition key, you would have to include that as well (`uuid = :some_value`). If you want to query across different partition keys then you either need to use a GSI which has some other value as partition key which encompasses all the items you want, or you need to do a scan.

Comment: @404 can you please give me an example of a piece of code so I can try it?

Comment: @PuneetJindal I don't know **go** at all so can't help you code-wise, but I do know how dynamodb works so have only commented from that perspective.